# Mysql query inside another one to get reference from two tables

Tags: mysql

I've been looking around to find how to do this but can't find it.

I have a table of `purchases` that contains `barcode` and `user_id` fields.

This table has many rows of barcodes and ids, barcodes are all different, but user_ids can be multiple, like this:

[image]

I than have a different table of `accountings` with barcodes and NO user_ids.

I have to find the barcodes from `purchases` and extract data from `accountings` (where the barcode found in `purchases` is the same as the UPC OR ISRC [fields] in `accountings`)

[image]

I've tried like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM accountings
  WHERE UPC IN(SELECT barcode
                 FROM purchases
                 WHERE user_id = '740')
```

But it runs endlessly and doesn't work.

Any way to get this right?

Comment: @Nath no idea how to...

Comment: Scratch that. You don't need a join. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"foo IN (correlated subquery)"` predicate is going to each your lunch, along with your lunchbox, in terms of query performance, because of the way MySQL processes it. The subquery will get executed for each and every row in the outer query.  With a large set from the outer query, that turns into a whole lot of subquery executions.

---

For improved performance, if you have guaranteed uniqueness of the `"(barcode,userid)"` tuple in `purchases` table (which doesn't seem likely) a simple join will give you the specified resultset:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM accountings a
  JOIN purchases p
    ON p.barcode = a.upc
   AND p.user_id = '740'
```

That query will return "duplicate" rows from `accountings` if there are multiple rows in `purchases` with the same barcode for user_id = 740.

To fix that, one option is to add `"GROUP BY"` clause to collapse the duplicate rows; you just need a column, or set of columns, guaranteed to be unique in the `accountings` table. If you have a surrogate primary key named `id` for example:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM accountings a
  JOIN purchases p
    ON p.barcode = a.upc
   AND p.user_id = '740'
 GROUP BY a.id
```

---

But, in the more general case, an alternate approach is to use an inline view to get a list of distinct barcode values for a given user, and the use a JOIN operation to that set of barcode values:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM accountings a
  JOIN ( SELECT p.barcode
           FROM purchases p
          WHERE p.user_id = '740'
          GROUP BY p.barcode
       ) q
    ON q.barcode = a.upc
```

The inline view aliased as "`q`" gets a distinct list of barcode values for the specified user, and the rows from that query are used like a table (MySQL actually calls it a "derived table") by the outer query.

These aren't the only ways to get the resultset, but they are common approaches.

---

Appropriate indexes will improve performance with large sets:

```
... ON accountings (upc)

... ON purchases (user_id, barcode)
```

---

**FOLLOWUP**

The output from an EXPLAIN will show us the execution plan MySQL will use to execute the query. It's possible that the last query in my answer could reverse the order of the tables, to influence the execution plan:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM ( SELECT p.barcode
           FROM purchases p
          WHERE p.user_id = '740'
          GROUP BY p.barcode
       ) q
  JOIN accountings a
    ON a.upc = q.barcode
```

I thought the MySQL optimizer is smart enough to figure that out without us having to change the order of the tables; best clues to performance improvements are usually found in the output from an `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Comment: This last query works fine in SequelPro, but is not running right in local (MAMP), meaning I get a loooooong waiting and no result (and no error neither).
My accountings has 175.000 records tho... Is that probably the reason? If so, is there a good solution to this?

Comment: @Mr.Web: With 175,000 rows in the `accountings` table, that's cries out for an index with a leading column of `"upc"`. Adding an `"ORDER BY a.upc"` should help MySQL decide to use that index. An `"EXPLAIN SELECT ..."` will show the access plan MySQL is using. The inline view query cries out for an index with leading columns of "`(user_id, barcde)`", so the EXPLAIN for that inner query will show "Using index", rather than a "Using filesort" operation. (It may be a benefit to reverse the order of the inline view and the accountings table in the FROM clause. `EXPLAIN` will show if plan differs.

Answer (score 2):

Your query looks fine as you can see [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1db7f/1)

Make sure `user_id` is a `string` and not an `int` because you're querying it as a `string`.

Comment: With MySQL, that correlated subquery is going to be executed for each row returned in the outer query; for large sets, that is going to be whole lot of executions, performance is going to be excruciating on large sets, especially if appropriate indexes are not available. The EXPLAIN output will show "DEPENDENT SUBQUERY" or something like that.

Comment: Since he said his query doesn't work, I just pointed out that maybe he's querying the wrong data type and showed him that his query will work if correct data types are used. But you are right, on a large set, his query will have a performance issue.

Comment: I clued in on "it runs endlessly"; you are right, there is nothing "wrong" with the SQL text; it's valid syntax, and it should (eventually) return the specified resultset, as your demonstration on a smaller set undoubtedly demonstrates.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try a JOIN. ([mysql JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)). The following will give you a table matched by barcode:

```
SELECT * FROM accountings a
LEFT JOIN purchases p ON a.UPC=p.barcode
```

Now that you have that table, you can build the query up to the full size you want it to be:

```
SELECT *
FROM accountings a
LEFT JOIN purchases p ON a.UPC=p.barcode
WHERE p.user_id='740'
```

I hope this also makes the concept of a LEFT JOIN clear. It'll add tables together and browse through combined data. It'll get all data though, from both accountings and purchases.

But I think Nath got it better by saying you probably have an int.